# Expand object properties as markup attributes

Tags: html, grails

In a grails taglib i am using markup builder for creating a markup that looks like this

```
a(href: '#', class: 'show-modal', properties) {
    mkp.yield '+'
}
```

In this case *properties* is a formatted set of object properties: `{data-internet=true, data-desc=Lorem ipsum}`

I need to expand properties as html5 data attributes. to get something like this.

`<a href="#" class="show-modal" data-internet=true, data-desc=Lorem ipsum>`

Right now instead of this I am getting this result

`<a href="#" class="show-modal">{data-internet=true, data-desc=Lorem ipsum}+</a>`

This a grails taglib sample:

```
def test = { attrs ->
    MarkupBuilder markupBuilder = new MarkupBuilder(out)

    Map properties = ['data-internet': true, 'data-desc': 'Lorem ipsum...']

    markupBuilder.a(href: '', properties) {
        mkp.yield 'More info'
    }
}
```

When from a view I render `<g:test/>` I get this:

`<a href="">{data-internet=true, data-desc=Lorem ipsum...}More info</a>`

And I am expecting this:

`<a href="" data-internet='true', data-desc='Lorem ipsum...'>More info</a>`

Thank you for your time and for some idea

Comment: Can you change your example so it can be run and show the output you say you're getting?

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates. I just added a sample

Comment: Not at a computer, but have you tried the spread-map operator: `markupBuilder.a(href: '', *:properties)`

Comment: Thanks again tim. Spread-map operator do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spread-map operator to unwrap the map and pass each entry as if it were a parameter:

```
markupBuilder.a(href: '', *:properties) {
    mkp.yield '+'
}
```